# Mobile verification in meteor web/mobile app?

Tags: meteor

I want to include mobile verification for the users in my app.Tried adding the accounts-phone package ::***$ meteor add okland:accounts-phone ***
but error was shown while including that package.

[Edit:1]
*=> Errors while adding packages:

While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint npm-bcrypt@=0.7.7 is not satisfied by npm-bcrypt
0.7.8_2.
Constraints on package "npm-bcrypt":
* npm-bcrypt@=0.7.8_2 <- accounts-password 1.1.1
* npm-bcrypt@=0.7.7 <- okland:accounts-phone 0.0.10*

Comment: Did the `accounts-phone` package not install correctly (i.e. is it outdated?) or were you just having trouble setting it up? What error was shown? In general, you're leaving out a lot of details about what you have done/tried, what does not work etc. Verification by phone is not an easy feat, so I don't think anyone will write a package for you here.

Comment: @Oskar while installing ***$meteor add okland:accounts-phone***, I m getting the error...=> Errors while adding packages:             
                                              
*While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint npm-bcrypt@=0.7.7 is not satisfied by npm-bcrypt
0.7.8_2.
Constraints on package "npm-bcrypt":
* npm-bcrypt@=0.7.8_2 <- accounts-password 1.1.1
* npm-bcrypt@=0.7.7 <- okland:accounts-phone 0.0.10*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the older versions of bycrpt and the old accounts-base package it depends on. I recently made a pull request to the okland:accounts-phone package which updates accounts-phone to depend on accounts-password and a newer bycrpt version.

Alternatively, if you don't want to wait, you can download his repo locally ([okland:accounts-phone](https://github.com/okland/accounts-phone)) into a packages dir at the root level of your project, and change the packages.js file as such:

```
Package.describe({
    name         : 'accounts-phone',

--skipped some lines--

Package.onUse(function (api) {
-api.use('npm-bcrypt@=0.7.8_2', 'server');
+api.use('npm-bcrypt@=0.8.7_1', 'server');

-api.use('accounts-base@1.0.2', ['client', 'server']);
+api.use('accounts-password@1.2.14', ['client', 'server']);

// Export Accounts (etc) to packages using this one.

-api.imply('accounts-base@1.0.2', ['client', 'server']);
+api.imply('accounts-password@1.2.14', ['client', 'server']);
```

(Make sure to get rid of the '+' and '-', they're just there to indicate what's deleted and what's new). Then, add the local using meteor add accounts-phone'. It will work just fine.